# HTTP Post Requests Swift 5 with List of JSON objects

Tags: json, swift, express, serialization, httprequest

Hello I am using Swift 5 to make an HTTP POST request, the request returns a list of JSON Objects which I believe is causing my error, and I can't seem to find a solution as I have scoured almost every example I could find on stackoverflow and youtube, and Apples documentation, even though this seems like a basic concept. 
Here is what my response would look like:

```
[
        {
        "_id": "---------------",
        "phone_number": "xxx-xxx-xxx"
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "LastName",
        "gender": "Female",
        "verified": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "---------------",
        "phone_number": "xxx-xxx-xxx"
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "LastName",
        "gender": "Female",
        "verified": true
    }
]
```

The code I am using to make my HTTP Request is:

```
        let url = URL(string: "URLString")!
        let json: [String:Any] = ["phone_number":phoneNumber]
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        do{
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
        }catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        //HTTP Headers
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //URL data task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print("Error!")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else{
                print("Error fetching data")
                return
            }

            do {
                guard let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] else {
                    print("Unable to serialize response!") //FAILS HERE EVERY TIME
                    return
                }
                print(responseJSON)
                print("WOO made it!")
            }catch let error {
                print("Error with response!")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

I am not sure what the issue is exactly but I have indicated where it fails, and I have tried printing out the data before it converts it just to make sure it isn't empty and it says like 2000 bytes so I know its not empty. My guess is that there is a problem because it is in the format of a list of objects, rather than just one object as most of the examples have shown. I also am having some issues with my HTTP body being nil on my express server end sometimes, so Not sure if I am doing that part wrong. But as of Now I just want to be able to parse my response So I can begin debugging the rest. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `[[String:Any]]` instead of `[String:Any]`

```
guard let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] else {
    print("Unable to serialize response!") //FAILS HERE EVERY TIME
    return
 }
```

But it's better using `JSONDecoder`

```
 do {
    let res = try JSONdecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
 }
 catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

---

Correct json

```
[
    {
        "_id": "---------------",
        "phone_number": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "LastName",
        "gender": "Female",
        "verified": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "---------------",
        "phone_number": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "LastName",
        "gender": "Female",
        "verified": true
    }
]
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id, phoneNumber, firstName, lastName: String
    let gender: String
    let verified: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case phoneNumber = "phone_number"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case gender, verified
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Such a small issue saved me! Really appreciate it.